# how to show or hide panel on mouseover of button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to hide or show Panel on when the user mouse over the button

But I am not getting any clue how to do this.I tried in the following way using javascript

but it shows error element is not known property name ..please help me..

My java script code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

         function SetMouseOver(element) {
         element.Panel1.visible="True";
          }
         function SetMouseOut(element) {
         element.Panel1.visible="False";
         }
         </script>
```

my asp.mark up code:

```
    <td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  class="classnameL" Text="SUMIFS" 
          Width="100%" onmouseover="SetMouseOver()" 
            />
   </td>
```

My Html:

```
      <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="IssueResponse"        MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Codebehind="IssueResponse.aspx.cs" %>
       <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" %>

      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head runat="server">
      <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
         </script>
   ----
   -----           
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
   <table>
  <tr>
          <td><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  class="classnameL"     Text="SUMIFS" 
                Width="100%" onmouseover="SetMouseOver()" 
                  />

  </td>
 </tr>

  </table>

 ------
 ------
  <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Visible="False">
  -------
  -   -------
  </asp:Panel>

      </div>

  </form>
   </body>
  </html>
```

tHIS IS CODE FOR VBA

```
Option Compare Database
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Private Sub cmd_costDifferential_Click()

 If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_CostDifferential")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_CostDifferential"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Cost Differential"
Me.Requery



End Sub

Private Sub cmd_costiszero_Click()

 If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Cost_is_zero")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Cost_is_zero"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Cost is zero"
Me.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Export_Click()

Call ExceExportfile



End Sub

Private Sub cmd_FinacneApproval_Click()

If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Finance_approval")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Finance_approval"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Finance Approval"
Me.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmd_FinanceRjected_Click()



If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Finance_rejected")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Finance_rejected"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Finance Rjected"
Me.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmd_highvolume_Click()




If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_HigerVolume")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_HigerVolume"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Higher Volume"
Me.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Multiplesku_Click()

If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_multiplesku_all")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_multiplesku_all"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Multiple sku "
Me.Requery


End Sub

Private Sub cmd_NegativeMargin_Click()



 If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Negative_margin")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Negative_margin"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Negative Margin"
Me.Requery


End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Overdue_Click()

 If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Award_overdue")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Award_overdue"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Award Overdue"
Me.Requery



End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Supplyapproval_Click()

 If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Supply_approval")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Supply_approval"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Supply Approval"
Me.Requery


End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Supplyrejected_Click()

If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Supply_rejected")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Supply_rejected"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Supply Rejected"
Me.Requery

End Sub

Private Sub cmd_TenderPrice_Click()


If rst Is Nothing Then
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    End If
     Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_Tender_price")
    Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)

Me.qry_report_filter.SourceObject = "Query.qry_Tender_price"
Me.lblReportName.Caption = "Report for Tender Price"
Me.Requery



End Sub

Private Sub cmd_Upload_Click()



Dim ABook As Workbook
Dim ASheet As Worksheet


'Public objCon As New ADODB.Connection
Dim lp As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SQL As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()

'Me.frmUploaderrorreport.SourceObject = ""

If ifTableExists("Data$_ImportErrors") = True Then

DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Data$_ImportErrors"


End If

Dim Answer As Integer

Answer = MsgBox("Please use the attached excel template for uploading the data in the prescribed format ", vbYesNo, "Uplod Master file ")

If Answer = 7 Then

'Me.lblwarningforupload.Visible = False
Me.Repaint
'Me.Refresh
Exit Sub
End If

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qry_Delete")
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
'Me.lblwarningforupload.Visible = True

Dim dlg As FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With dlg

.Title = "Select the Excel file to import"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx", 1
.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 2
On Error GoTo end1:

If .Show = -1 Then
StrFileName = .SelectedItems(1)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "tb_MasterData", StrFileName, True, "Data!"
Else

Exit Sub
End If




MsgBox ("Report has been uploaded ")
'Me.frmUploaderrorreport.Visible = True
Exit Sub
 ' Me.frmUploaderrorreport.SourceObject = "Table.TenderMaster$_ImportErrors"

'Me.lblwarningforupload.Visible = False
Exit Sub

end1:

'MsgBox ("File is in the wrong format")

End With

'Me.lblwarningforupload.Visible = False


End Sub
Public Function ifTableExists(tblName As String) As Boolean

    If DCount("[Name]", "MSysObjects", "[Name] = '" & tblName & "'") = 1 Then

        ifTableExists = True

    End If

End Function


Public Sub ExceExportfile()

On Error GoTo Command13_Click_Err
Me.qry_report_filter.SetFocus
'DoCmd.GoToControl "Policy Ref"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectAllRecords
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With xlapp
.Workbooks.Add
.ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
False
.Cells.Select
.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
.Visible = True
.Range("a1").Select

End With

Command13_Click_Exit:
Exit Sub
Command13_Click_Err:
MsgBox Error$
Resume Command13_Click_Exit




'DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frm_Server_Data", acFormatXLS ''_
'strPath & "\ServerData.xls" ', AutoStart:=-1


Exit Sub


Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim varField As Variant
Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long
Dim wb As String
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
'On Error GoTo Err_Cancel_Click

rst.MoveFirst
lngRow = 0
Do While Not rst.EOF
    lngCol = 0
    For Each varField In rst.Fields
    On Error Resume Next

    oBook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lngRow + 1, lngCol + 1) = IIf(lngRow = 0, rst.Fields(lngCol).Name, varField.Value)
   ' On Error GoTo Err_Cancel_Click
        lngCol = lngCol + 1
    Next
    If lngRow > 0 Then rst.MoveNext
    lngRow = lngRow + 1
Loop
oSheet.Rows.AutoFit


oSheet.Columns.AutoFit
'oBook.SaveAs FileName:=wb
oExcel.Visible = True 'or oExcel.Quit




Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oBook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
'Exit_Cancel_Click:
 '   Exit Sub

'Err_Cancel_Click:
 '   MsgBox Err.Description
  '  Resume Exit_Cancel_Click
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Show us the html of panel as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend using jQuery as it allows for you to remove the `onmouseover` attribute from the button itself and clean up your markup, like this:

```
$('.classnameL').mouseover(function() {
    $('.panel1').hide();
});

$('.classnameL').mouseout(function() {
    $('.panel1').show();
});

<td>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
                class="classnameL" Text="SUMIFS" 
                Width="100%" />
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" class="panel1" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

use this JavaScript:

```
function doHide()
{
    document.getElementById("Panel1").style.display = "none";
}

function doShow()
{
    document.getElementById("Panel1").style.display = "inline";
}
```